# Error when trying to compile app using boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::construct<T>

Tags: c++, boost, g++, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I'm receiving a strange compilation error when trying to use `construct<T>()` method of a `boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory` class. I'm using the Boost library in 1.48 version and GCC in 4.6.3 version.

The problem is that when I'm creating a `managed_shared_memory object` (which is not a member of the struct) and then I'm trying to construct any object by using it's `construct<T>()` method, the compilation succeeds:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
namespace proc = boost::interprocess;

template <typename _T>
void TFunc() {
    proc::managed_shared_memory mem;
    mem = proc::managed_shared_memory(proc::create_only, "mem1", 1024);
    int* ob1 = mem.construct<int>("i1") ();
}
```

Although, when the `managed_shared_memory` object is defined inside a struct and then created, the compilation of usage of `construct<T>()` method fails :

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
namespace proc = boost::interprocess;

template <typename _T>
void TFunc() { 
    struct MemoryHandler {
        proc::managed_shared_memory mem;
    } handler;

    handler.mem = proc::managed_shared_memory(proc::create_only, "mem2", 1024);
    int* ob2 = handler.mem.construct<int>("i2") ();  // failure
}
```

with the following GCC error, pointing at the line with `construct` usage method:

```
error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
error: expected ',' or ';' before 'int'
```

Unfortunately I have not tested it against another versions of Boost and GCC, so I don't know if it's a bug of Boost/GCC or a feature.

Has anyone struggled with similar error or know what can be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown a complete example that demonstrates the error, so I can only guess, but I suspect the line that fails is inside a template and `handler` is a dependent type.

To fix it you need to tell the compiler that `construct` is a function template:

```
int* ob2 = handler.mem.template construct<int>("i2") ();
                       ^^^^^^^^
```

See the [C++ Templates FAQ](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#disambiguation) for more information.

And next time please post a complete example so others can reproduce the exact problem, instead of making people guess. For example, here is a minimal, complete example that shows the same error:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>

namespace proc = boost::interprocess;

struct MemoryHandler{
        proc::managed_shared_memory mem;
} handler;

template<typename T> void f(T handler)
{
  handler.mem = proc::managed_shared_memory(proc::create_only, "mem2", 10);
  int* ob2 = handler.mem.construct<int>("i2") ();  // failure
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, that was the case. I've also applied suggested changes to the original post.